# Using AngularJS ngKeyup on a div rather than an input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've set up a Plunker with some example code: http://plnkr.co/edit/upExTHzpkwtZ45mdikFr?p=preview

The very succinct question is: I'm trying to use AngularJS' `ng-keyUp` directive. In the docs I've only seen is used on an input, although I'm trying to capture keypresses anywhere on the page rather than just inside an input box. Like so:

```
// view

<div ng-keyup="keyPress($event)">
     // The bulk of my controller's view goes in here
</div>

// inside controller

$scope.keyPress = function(e){
     console.log(e);
}
```

Again, see the Plunker above for an example. Currently, it doesn't work at all and nothing is logged. How can I get it to work properly?

Comment: I think that you should rather use ng-click: `<div ng-click="keyPress($event)">` because use on your page just click on your div. But maybe I don't understand your case.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to give the div element focus,  or use `tabindex="1"`

Comment: Perfect, `tabindex="1"` got it working. It had a weird `:focus` outline around it when I used this though, which I fixed by changing the css of `.container:focus {outline: 0;}`

Comment: this method worked for me  first I have to click on div then only  keys are detected. I am working on Django and using templates.

Answer (score 0):

There is always good old vanilla coffee-script '.'

```
document.onkeypress = (e) ->
  console.log String.fromCharCode(charCode)
```