# Using ng-keyup on non-input html tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, keypress, keyup

I have to use ng-keyup on some arrow keys. i am only able to use it on textarea and input `type="text"` tags.

I want to be able to use it on a div or body tag rather than the input tags so the user can just press arrow key when page loads to see the change. How do I do this?

[Using AngularJS ngKeyup on a div rather than an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900455/using-angularjs-ngkeyup-on-a-div-rather-than-an-input)

I already tried using tabindex as is suggested by this answer but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by shifting both the controller and ng-keyup to the body tag.